# What would be a good pipeline to create a scalable, distributed web crawler and scraper?

Tags: database, performance, scrapy, scalability, pipeline

**I would like to build a semi-general crawler and scraper for pharmacy product webpages.**

I know that most of the webs are not equal, but most of the URLs I have in a list follow one specific type of logic:

1. For example, by using Microdata, JSON-ld, etc. I can already scrape a certain group of webpages.
2. By using XPath stored in configuration files I can crawl and scrape some other websites.
3. And other methods work good for the rest of the websites and if I can already extract the information I need from 80% of the data, I would be more than happy with the result.

*In essence*, **I am worried about building a good pipeline to address issues related with monitoring (to handle webpages that suddenly change their structure), scalability and performance.**

I have thought of the following pipeline (not taking into account storage):

Create 2 main spiders. One that crawls the websites given their domains. It gets all the URLs inside a webpage (obeying robots.txt of course) and puts it into a queue system that stores the URLs that are *scrape-ready*. Then, the second spider picks up the last URL in the Queue and extracts it using either metadata, XPath or any other method. Then, this is put again into another queue system that will be eventually be handled by a module that puts all the data in the queue into a database (which I still do not know if it should be SQL or NoSQL).

The advantages of this system is that by putting queues in between the main processes of extraction and storage, parallelization and scalability becomes feasible.

Is there anything flawed in my logic? What are the things that I am missing?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, that approach will work; my team and I have built numerous crawlers based on that structure, and they are efficient.

That said, if you're looking to scale, I would recommend a slightly different approach. For my own large-scale crawler, I have a 3-program approach.

1. There is one program to **schedule** which handles which URLs to download.
2. There is a program to perform the actual **downloading**
3. There is a program to **extract** the information from the downloaded pages and add in new links for the program that handles the scheduling.

The other major recommendation is that if you're using cURL at all, you'll want to use the cURL multi interface and a FIFO queue to handle sending the data from the scheduler to the downloader.

The advantage of this approach is that it separates out the processing from the downloading. This allows you to scale up your crawler by adding new servers and operating in parallel.

At Potent Pages, this is the architecture we use for our site spider that handles downloading hundreds of sites simultaneously. We use MySQL for the data saving (links, etc), but as you scale up, you'll need to do a lot of optimization. Plus phpmyadmin starts to break down if you have a lot of databases, but having one database per site really speeds up the parsing process so you don't have to go through millions of rows of data.